# Difficulty Setting Up Swagger for a Spring Boot Maven Project

Tags: spring, swagger

I'm currently working on a Java Spring Boot project with Maven and am encountering difficulties while trying to set up Swagger documentation for my API. The project builds successfully, but I'm unable to make Swagger work as expected. I've included the relevant code below for reference:

CrudApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.objetivar.crud.model") // Substitua pelo pacote das suas entidades
public class CrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Address.java

```
package com.objetivar.crud.model;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String city;
    private String state;
    private Long zipCode;
    private String description;
    private String address;
    private Long number;
    private String complement;
    private String complementoEndereco;
    private String bairro;
}
```

AddressRepository.java

```
package com.objetivar.crud.repository;
import com.objetivar.crud.model.Address;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {
    // Você pode adicionar consultas personalizadas aqui, se necessário
}
```

AddressService.java

```
package com.objetivar.crud.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.objetivar.crud.repository.AddressRepository;
import com.objetivar.crud.model.Address;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class AddressService {
    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AddressService(AddressRepository addressRepository) {
        this.addressRepository = addressRepository;
    }

    public Address createAddress(Address address) {
        return addressRepository.save(address);
    }

    public Address getAddressById(Long id) {
        return addressRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public List<Address> getAllAddresses() {
        return addressRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Address updateAddress(Long id, Address updatedAddress) {
        Address existingAddress = addressRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        if (existingAddress != null) {
            existingAddress.setCity(updatedAddress.getCity());
            existingAddress.setState(updatedAddress.getState());
            existingAddress.setZipCode(updatedAddress.getZipCode());
            existingAddress.setDescription(updatedAddress.getDescription());
            existingAddress.setAddress(updatedAddress.getAddress());
            existingAddress.setNumber(updatedAddress.getNumber());
            existingAddress.setComplement(updatedAddress.getComplement());
            existingAddress.setComplementoEndereco(updatedAddress.getComplementoEndereco());
            existingAddress.setBairro(updatedAddress.getBairro());
            addressRepository.save(existingAddress);
        }
        return existingAddress;
    }

    public void deleteAddress(Long id) {
        addressRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

AddressController.java

```
package com.objetivar.crud.controllers;

import com.objetivar.crud.model.Address;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.objetivar.crud.service.AddressService;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/addresses")  // Define a raiz dos endpoints para esta entidade
public class AddressController {
    private final AddressService addressService;

    @Autowired
    public AddressController(AddressService addressService) {
        this.addressService = addressService;
    }

    // Endpoint para criar um novo endereço
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Address> createAddress(@RequestBody Address address) {
        Address newAddress = addressService.createAddress(address);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newAddress, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    // Endpoint para buscar um endereço pelo ID
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Address> getAddressById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Address address = addressService.getAddressById(id);
        if (address != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(address, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    // Endpoint para buscar todos os endereços
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Address>> getAllAddresses() {
        List<Address> addresses = addressService.getAllAddresses();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(addresses, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // Endpoint para atualizar um endereço existente
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Address> updateAddress(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Address address) {
        Address updatedAddress = addressService.updateAddress(id, address);
        if (updatedAddress != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedAddress, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    // Endpoint para excluir um endereço pelo ID
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAddress(@PathVariable Long id) {
        addressService.deleteAddress(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

aplication.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/crud_objetivar
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8081
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.objetivar</groupId>
    <artifactId>crud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crud</name>
    <description>CRUD SISTEMA OCR</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Suas dependências aqui -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>java-11</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

SwaggerConfig.java

```
package com.objetivar.crud.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.oas.annotations.EnableOpenApi;

@Configuration
@EnableOpenApi
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.objetivar.crud.controllers")) // Substitua pelo pacote dos seus controladores
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

I've tried different dependencies and versions, but I can't get Swagger to function as intended. While the project builds successfully, I'm unable to test the API using Swagger.

Here are the steps I've already taken:

Updated Swagger dependencies to the latest versions.
Added the Swagger configuration in SwaggerConfig.java.
Ensured that the controllers are correctly annotated with @RestController.
Checked the URL, which should be http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html.
I'm seeking assistance and guidance on resolving this issue. If you've encountered similar challenges or have insights into what might be causing this problem, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! Misconfiguration of SwaggerConfig and incompatibility of some dependencies versions in pom.xml files.

Answer (score 1):

You are using SpringBoot 3.x and an earlier version of Swagger. Swagger was integrated in the Spring environment and is currently available in

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

alternatively you have to use swagger2.
See:

https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: Hello! I have tried different versions of swagger, Spring, JPA and postgreSQL, but can't make it work.

Comment: Have you tried this exact version? What errors are you getting exactly.

Comment: Pasted the error in chatGPT and got this: The error "Not a managed type: class com.objetivar.crud.model.Address" indicates that Spring Data JPA cannot recognize the `Address` class as a JPA entity.
I have done every steps it showed me, but could not fix the problem. All anotations are set, as you can see in the code above.

Comment: This is the output error: 'Error creating bean with name 'addressService' defined in file [/home/wanderson-silva/Desktop/DESKTOP/wanderson/CAJUPE/crud/target/classes/com/objetivar/crud/service/AddressService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'addressRepository' defined in com.objetivar.crud.repository.AddressRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.objetivar.crud.model.Address'